# cannot open libmpfr.so.4 after update on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04

Today I updated my laptop to Ubuntu 18.04. Now I try to run a program for my bachelor thesis, but it gives me the following error message:

"error while loading shared libraries: libmpfr.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"

I did a bit of research, and I think libmpfr4 has been droppen in this ubuntu version. Is there any way I can solve this?

Answer (score 0):

The package `libmpfr4` has indeed been dropped in 18.04

It was replaced by the package `libmpfr6`.

Comment: I thought so. So do i need to wait for the program i want to use to be updated ? Or can I do something about it myself?

Comment: The application is complaining about a missing *file*, not a missing *package*. So try installing the package (to provide the file), then running your application. The worst that can happen is that it fails with a different error message. Remember to file a bug report with the application developers - they can only fix problems that they are aware of.

Comment: When I try to install the package, I get the message libmpfr4:i386 is already the newest version (3.1.4-1).

Comment: Are you sure you're using the right package name? The name changed.

Comment: I tried a few. - libmpfr4, libmpfr4:i386, libmpfr-dev. Which one should I use?